# Symfony 4 form validation not showing all errors

Tags: forms, symfony, validation

I'm using Symfony 4.1 and have a strange behaviour with form validation. Some errors are rendered in the label and some are not.

The entity looks like:

```
class Vehicle
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(
     *     groups = { "edit" },
     *     message="Fahrzeugnummer wird benötigt"
     * )
     */
    private $fzgnr_nvr;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(
     *     groups = { "edit" },
     *     message="Hersteller wird benötigt"
     * )
     */
    private $hersteller;
```

Here is the formbuilder

```
$builder
    ->add('fzgnrNvr', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'Fahrzeug (NVR)',
    ])
    ->add('histbezMitnr', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'Historische Bezeichnung'
    ])
    ->add('hersteller', TextType::class, [
       'label' => 'Hersteller'
    ])
```

The twig looks like

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.fzgnrNvr) }}
    {{ form_row(form.histbezMitnr) }}
    {{ form_row(form.hersteller) }}
    {{ form_row(form.baujahr) }}
    {{ form_row(form.eigentuemer) }}
```

form_errors I have added because then the error for form.fzgnrNvr are not rendered. The errors where rendered different and I cannot find what is wrong.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XM1i2.png)

In the debug the error is shown but not at the field. fzgnrNvr and hersteller are absolutely the same but renders the error different.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr6EM.png)

Answer (score 2):

Problem was the underscore in the database fields. Fields should not be named fzgnr_nvr but fzgnrnvr or fzgnrNvr. After removing all underscores from the database fields everything works as it should.

Comment: Just to note, this problem appears when entity property is named "shortDescription" and form field is named "short_description" .. they should be the same "shortDescription".

No other problems, form will work as expected, but errors will not show.